# Chrome cannot find js file with live edit active - Intellij

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea

intellij ide doesn't complain about the source destination but while i have live edit running everything works smooth except that the .js and .css files from bootstrap are not loaded because it cannot find the files.

[image]

If I open the source code and click on the link it gives me a 404.

[image]

Any idea about the reason and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add .. before source

```
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

IDEA built-in webserver serves files from `http://localhost:63342/<project root>`. Forward slashes in URLs, like `<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js">` tell the browser to resolve them relative to the web server root (`localhost:63342`), causing 404 errors.

If you like to use URLs relative to server root (the ones starting with slash), you have to change the default web path on built-in web server (to map your project to the server root). To do this, you need editing your system hosts file accordingly - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559. Or, just use a 'normal' web server (Apache, etc.) to host your files and configure it in the way you like.

If using absolute paths is not a requirement, just change paths to relative to current page: `<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`